# IndexError: string index out of range ADF - Databricks - Python

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I'm passing a UDF value from a JSON table through Azure Data Factory as the following:

"schema_array": "[('creationdate','timestamp'),('agent_name_txt','string'),('email','string'),('agent_hire_date','date'),('days_since_hire_text','int'),('department_auto','string')]"

But when my databricks notebooks accepts it and the indexing is interpreted as a string (which it needs to be set as an array.

This will work in my notebook by accepting the value when hardcoded, but not when passing from ADF. Here's the data type when pass from ADF: print(type(schema_array))
<class 'str'>

In need to know how to transform this (I'm in python) so my notebook will accept it as an array. I've tried to set it as an array in ADF many different ways, but will get the following error: "The variable 'udf' of type 'String' cannot be initialized or updated with value of type 'Array'. The variable 'udf' only supports values of types 'String'".

I'm running it through a schema mapping function to transform my data frame:

```
def string_to_datatype(datatype):
  if datatype == 'timestamp':
    final_datatype = t.TimestampType()
  elif datatype == 'integer' or datatype == 'int':
    final_datatype = t.IntegerType()
  elif datatype == 'date':
    final_datatype = t.DateType()
  else: final_datatype = t.StringType()

  return final_datatype

schema = t.StructType([])

for s in schema_array:
    schema = schema.add(t.StructField(s[0], string_to_datatype(s[1])))
```

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK**, Currently in ADF it is not supported to pass the arrays as parameters to Databricks Notebook.

This is the reason for the above error as it is doing the list operations with string.

So, pass it as a string from ADF to Notebook, convert it to list in Notebook and use as per your requirement.

Use `eval('variable_name')` for it.

**My Repro for your reference:**

[image]

Passing String variable to Notebook:

[image]

**Notebook run:**

[image]